# Slim framework ignoring custom error handler on Fatal Error

Tags: php, error-handling, slim

For the backend of my new SPA I want to pass the errors to the frontend in a nice way by using custom error and exception handlers.

I can add a custom error-handler to the slim framework like so:

```
$app->error(function (Exception $e) use ($app) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This however does not capture fatal errors. I also define a global default error-handler which captures fatal errors as long as they occur outside the Slim context.

```
set_error_handler(function() {
    echo "Huston we got a problem";
    die();
});
```

This handler gets called fine when I do this:

```
require "asdasd.php"; // trigger fatal error
$app->get("/test", $authenticate, function () use ($app) {
    // useful stuff
});
```

but not when I do this:

```
$app->get("/test", $authenticate, function () use ($app) {
    require "asdasd.php"; // trigger fatal error
    // useful stuff
});
```

The last demo actually seems to fire the php default error handler.

Does anybody know how I can get Slim not to do magic on my errors and have the toplevel handler be fired or have Slims custom errorhandler catch fatal errors?

Comment: If you have debug parameter on Slim config set to true the custom error handler won't catch fatal errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();

register_shutdown_function('fatal_handler');

function fatal_handler()
{
    if(! is_null(error_get_last()))
    {
        echo('There is a fatal error!');
    }
}

require 'xxxx';

$app->get('/test', function () use ($app)
{
    echo('This is a test');
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: I tried this, Slim is still printing it's error as well

Comment: @anthonygore What's the error said? Is it a fatal error or just exception?